# How to create text expander with Python?

Tags: python, windows, text

I would like to write a program that replaces a certain sequence of symbols with other symbols (text expander).

This program should run in the background of the OS, and if user writes the defined symbols anywhere (for example, in this post), it is automatically replaced with another defined symbol.

For example: `'delta_low' -> 'δ'`

I know how to detect and replace symbols. But how should I implement the code so that it runs in the background?

Note: I am currently focusing on Windows.

Comment: Have you seen https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm?

Comment: I have seen a lot of programs for hot keys, but I want to understand how it works and how I can implement it by myself with Python.